e2fsck errors on /dev/loop0
Raspberry Pi 5 8GB
Having problems shrinking /dev/sdb.
Getting e2fsck errors when in /dev/loop0 at step 6
/dev/sdb has a working Pi OS to shrink and is not mounted (32GB)
/dev/sda1 mounted in /mnt (256GB ext4)

sudo e2fsck -B 512 -f -y -n -C 0 /dev/sdb2

runs error free.  no errors reported

sudo dcfldd bs=512 if=/dev/sdb2 of=/mnt/20240728-0801.img

sudo fdisk -l /mnt/20240728-0801.img


p1  starting 8192
p2  starting 1056768

lsblk shows no loop0

sudo losetup bs=512 /dev/loop0 /mnt/20240728-0801.img -o $((1056768*512))

sudo gparted /dev/loop0  resize has multiple e2fsck errors so I will try to to resize next image without gparted


one hour later
This is a new image and did not try to resize with gparted
Running commands manually.

sudo e2fsck -B 512 -f -y -n -C 0 /dev/loop0

multiple errors found and repaired same as gparted resize from earlier image.  Lots of entries moved to lost and found
How do I find the problem with e2fsck errors reported with loopback device.
Is it a bad dcfldd copy or loopback error?
How do I troubleshoot this error?
update 20240728-1728 cst ut-5:
my micro-sd card had bad blocks.
looking for a good micro-SD and my problems may go away.
Update 20240730
micro-sd cards were ok.  Card reader was introducing bad blocks.
New card reader ran error free on 2 complete backups, resizing, and restore back to a micro-sd.  Problem found and corrected.
30GB dcfldd backup sdb to image changed from 42 minutes to 14 minutes with new card reader.

Presumably this is a typo since the fdisk subsequently reports the image does contain two partitions: sudo dcfldd bs=512 if=/dev/sdb2<<.   You might want to use -P with losetup instead of manually specifying the offset.
